# Accessing javascript arraylist in struts <s:select>

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, select, struts

I am trying to create a dropdown list using struts. I want to load the option values in the select element from a javascript arraylist (say. a separate javascript file).
How can I do so?

```
<s:select list="countries"></s:select>
```

I have seen an example that it can be done in plain javascript. How can I do so in struts select element?

Thank you.

**EDIT** : I want to populate the elements of the  element using a javascript arraylist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as with plain JavaScript; use the `id` attribute and proceed normally.

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit? I am trying to populate the list.

Comment: All the `<s:select>` tag does is render HTML. If you already have an example using JavaScript, you have all you need--give the `<s:select>` tag an `id` attribute so you can access it easily from JS, and use the example you already have.